# How do I get my Onchange function to work more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form where I've got a button that will add a set of form fields when you click it.  One of the form fields is a dropdown menu and I have a function so that when a certain option is picked from the dropdown menu, it populates another form field.  So far, it works on the original set of form fields that are shown when the page first loads but it won't work for the set of form fields that gets added.  How do I get it to work on both?  Here's my javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'>
</script><script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var p = $(this).closest('p');

        $(p).before('<p> <b>Quantity & Description:<\/b><br><textarea name="QuantityAndDescription" rows="10" cols="60"><\/textarea><br><b>Fabric Source:<\/b> <select name="FabricSource" onchange="changevalue(this.value)"><option value="">Select Fabric Source<\/option><option value="JEC">JEC Fabric<\/option><option value="Other">Other Fabric<\/option></select><br><b>Style# & Name:<\/b> <input type="text" name="Style#andName"><br><b>Fabric Width:<\/b> <input type="text" name="FabricWidth"><br><b>Repeat Information:<\/b> <input type="text" name="RepeatInfo" size="60"><input type="hidden" name="COM Required" /> <\/p><br>');
        return false;
    });
});

function changevalue(val) {
    if (val == "JEC") document.comform.RepeatInfo.value = "Per JEC Pattern";
}
//]]> 
</script>
```

Edit:

I got it to work using:
`function changevalue(val)
{
if(val=="JEC")
$("form#comform [name='RepeatInfo']").val("Per JEC Standard");
}`
instead of what I had before.  But now the problem is that when you select the triggering option, ALL the "RepeatInfo" form fields get populated with "Per JEC Standard", not just the one in the same set of form fields as the triggered selection.  How can I get this function to work for the added sets of form fields but not have ONE single selection change populating ALL of the "RepeatInfo" form fields in every set?

Answer (score 1):

In your dynamically generated HTML, you have this:

```
<select name="FabricSource" onchange="changevalue(this.value)">
```

But there is no `value` property on a select element. You instead would have to check `selectedIndex` or you could also use the jQuery `val` method.

You could try this instead:

```
<select name="FabricSource" onchange="changevalue($(this).val())">
```

And if that does not work, there may be better ways to handle this instead of putting it inline like this. However, I thought this answer would be the least amount of work for you to fix and get it running.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If it is going to work on the elemnts added on the go you have to use live() method.

So to be more specific.

If you already use jQuery for handling click event use it for handling change, as well. For example like that:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready({
    $('#add').click(function () {
    var p = $(this).closest('p');

    $(p).before('<p> <b>Quantity & Description:<\/b><br><textarea name="QuantityAndDescription" rows="10" cols="60"><\/textarea><br><b>Fabric Source:<\/b> <select name="FabricSource"><option value="">Select Fabric Source<\/option><option value="JEC">JEC Fabric<\/option><option value="Other">Other Fabric<\/option></select><br><b>Style# & Name:<\/b> <input type="text" name="Style#andName"><br><b>Fabric Width:<\/b> <input type="text" name="FabricWidth"><br><b>Repeat Information:<\/b> <input type="text" name="RepeatInfo" size="60"><input type="hidden" name="COM Required" /> <\/p><br>');
    return false;
    });

   $(":select").live('change', function(){
      changevalue($(this).val());
     });
   function changevalue(val) {
    if (val == "JEC") document.comform.RepeatInfo.value = "Per JEC Pattern";
   }
});   
</script>
```

I have not tested it so check the closures.

K

Comment: She is not using jQuery to do the event handling, it is inline in the HTML she is adding.

Comment: That does not mean that she cannot use jQuert for that and yes she would have to use live() for newly added elemnts? Therefore I do not see the reason for giving negatives for the answer.

Comment: In theory, this would also work, but just a note about some syntax:  The `:select` on your first line should be wrapped in quotes, and the `this` in the second line should be wrapped in jQuery, like `$(this)`. Although, probably you wouldn't want to target _all_ select boxes on the page, so going with an ID would probably be even better.

Comment: @kwicher I didn't downvote.  Though @Funka has pointed out some fundamental problems with your answer anyway.  I made my comment because your statement of "If it is going to work on the elements added on the go you have to use live()" which is incorrect, since they are inline statements.  live() is certainly a possible solution, but does not answer her question of why her current solution does not work (not to mention the problems mentioned by @Funka)

Comment: I agree that I made the tying errors because of haste. They are corrected now. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: @kwicher - I'm sorry, I've got pretty close to zero javascript knowledge so can you tell me where your code would go in the script?